# How to clear the cache by Magento Web Service

Tags: cache, web-services

I wonder if you have any way to clear caches Magento Web Service.
If not there how do I clear the cache programmatically ?

I need it just for the reason to be developing an application that integrates with Magento Management System, and has some processes that demands he be clean caches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701456/clear-magento-cache programmatically

```
Mage::app()->cleanCache();
```

Comment: Ok Thank you, have worked the first time, I can test more thoroughly just another afternoon.

I appreciate the help

Answer (score 2):

This code will help for sure

```
 $app = Mage::app(); if ($app != null) 
{    $cache = $app->getCache();    
if ($cache != null)    
{        $cache->clean();   
 } 
}
```